# Populating multidimensional array of enums

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to populate a multidimensional array of `enums` but I'm having some trouble.

The following code is as close as I can get but the array is of type `number` rather than my `enum` type `TileAssignment`.

Here are my code snippets:

board.ts

```
import { TileAssignment } from './tile-assignment.enum';

export class Board {

  width: number;
  height: number;
  boardTiles: TileAssignment[][];

  static fromJsonObj(boardObj: object): Board {

    const tiles = new Array<Array<TileAssignment>>();

    for (let i = 0; i < boardObj['BoardTiles'].length; i++) {
      const row: TileAssignment[]  = new Array<TileAssignment>();
      for (let y = 0; y < boardObj['BoardTiles'][i].length; y++) {
        const t = boardObj['BoardTiles'][i][y]['TileAssignment'];
        row.push(t);
        // row.push(TileAssignment[t]) pushes string
      }
      tiles.push(row);
    }

    return new Board(boardObj['Width'], boardObj['Height'], tiles)
  }

  constructor(w: number, h: number, tiles: TileAssignment[][]) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.boardTiles = tiles;
  }
}
```

tile-assignment.enum.ts:

```
export enum TileAssignment {
  Free,
  Mine,
  Exit
}
```

boardObj:

```
{
  "BoardTiles": [
    [
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 1
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 1
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 1
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 2
      },
      {
        "TileAssignment": 0
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Am I assigning the values to my array correctly or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should type the `boardObject` parameter more strongly than just `object`.  How about:

```
export interface BoardObject {
  Width: number,
  Height: number,
  BoardTiles: { TileAssignment: TileAssignment }[][]
}

export class Board {
  static fromJsonObj(boardObj: BoardObject): Board {
  // ⋮      
  }
// ⋮
}
```

Note that the `boardObj` example is missing the required `Width` and `Height` properties.  Does this work for you or is there some other problem?

Good luck.